# POST "\" Chained to every word in the String with retrofit httpclient

Tags: android, parsing, jakarta-ee, retrofit

I'm using retrofit as my HttpClient in my Android project.
and Weblogic Java EE on my server side.

My problem is that i'm trying to send JSONObject via. String to the server but for some reason "\" is chained to every word in the string.

For exmple:
When I send: **"{"DEPTNO":"777","DNAME":"test","LOC":"test"}"** as a string to the server,

I will get: **"{\"DEPTNO\":\"777\",\"DNAME\":\"test\",\"LOC\":\"test\"}"**

Tried working with String, Jackson and Gson converters on the Client side but all converters gave me the same results.

I can build a function on the server side that will drop that nonsense but before i'm going to do it I trying to find the easy way.

Has anyone faced with such a case?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem in past. so my solution is:

```
JsonStringObject = JsonStringObject.replaceAll("\\","");
```

Thats it. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer but when doing that i got:
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
JSONString = JSONString.replaceAll("\\\"","\"");
```

This way if there would be slashes in between the strings, they won't get deleted!

What i am doing is searching for a \" and replacing it with single ".

Comment: it's not changing the string, after the replaceAll function i'm still geting "{\"DEPTNO\":\"777\",\"DNAME\":\"test\",\"LOC\":\"test\"}"

Comment: i think you are not initializing it to a variable, you need to do this:
 str = str.replaceAll(arguments),  and not directly like this: str.replaceAll(arguments),  it's working fine on my end